# Referencing future ideas in abstract of a research paper

Tags: citations, abstract

Is it bad to reference ideas which have not yet been defined in detail within the abstract for a research paper? For example, if I have a section (lets say section 4) in my paper that defines a new concept such as "The Quadrilateral Optimization", within my abstract, would it be acceptable to write "The Quadrilateral Optimization (§4) excels specifically with points that are randomly generated."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A paper containing a concept *X* can be cited with respect to *X* if any one or more of the following applies:

- *X* is clearly defined
- An intuition of *X* is provided
- A constraint of *X* is explained
- An application of *X* is experimented
- An application concerning *X* is accounted
- A logically contradicting definition of *X* is theorized

A mere inclusion of the name of the concept *X* does not mean that it deserves to be cited

Comment: So does this still apply if "X" is ONLY defined within the paper that I am writing? Or must it be defined in another source?

Comment: Just to clarify, "X" in this case is a new idea that has not necessarily been defined elsewhere, only later on in the paper I am writing.

Comment: @Arman: If by *'defined'*, you mean clearly defined and you are sure that the concept *X* has not been defined before elsewhere, then by all means you may cite the paper with *X*.